# I dont understand that why Apple rejected my ios app Screenshots?

Tags: ios, screen, screenshot, review

Hi guys I got a problem about apple meta data rejected.I submitted my application but still apple reject my app because of 6.5inch screenshots.Where is the problem I don't udnerstand I ask they but I didn't receive any message please Do you know problem ?

Apple says,

We noticed that your screenshots do not sufficiently reflect your app in use.

Specifically, your 6.5-inch iPhone screenshots do not display the app in the correct device frame.
An attached my screenshots 
[image1](https://ibb.co/Wfn5f2F)

[image2](https://ibb.co/h1p9cQv)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because you are not using the correct template for the device.

For iPhone X or newer version you have to use iPhone X or newer version template.

Comment: Thanks your answer Nicolau ,but I used this screenshots 4 week ago, apple accepted its a new thing ? and you mean In screenshot ,Do I have to use iphone x or somethign like that devices  ,don't it ?

Comment: Yes, happend to me i had to upload the correct template.